# How to write gradient vector for logistic regression?

Tags: python, vectorization, logistic-regression

I am writing a function which gives the cost and gradients as output when the input is the feature matrix (X), response labels (y) and parameter vector (theta). I'm writing the vectorized form instead of using loops. In the last line of the function, my intention is to get all the gradients in a single vector (grad) by performing the shown matrix operation. However, in that line I'm getting a syntax error. How to overcome this issue? Code is given below:

```
def sigmoid(X):
   return 1/(1+np.exp(-X))

def costFunction(theta, X, y):

    #J=0
    m = y.size
    #grad = np.zeros(theta.shape)

    z = sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))

    J = (1/m)*(-(np.dot(y.T,np.log(z)))-(np.dot((np.ones(m)-y).T,np.log(np.ones(m)-z)))  #cost funct

    grad = (np.dot(X.T,z-y))   #problematic line of code

    return J, grad
```

Comment: The syntax error is because there is an open parenthesis in the previous line.

Comment: ok. got it. thanks